# Blank Screen After Magento Setup

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I have just installed fresh version of `Magento 2` locally with `XAMPP` but the admin panel shows me a blank screen

This is a screenshot of the problem:

[image]

Comment: Which magento version ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrong paths to Windows are generated. The fixed fix is

**Magento 2.3.0**

```
#/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template/File/Validator.php:114
```

the string

> `$realPath = $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path);`

```
to replace
```

> `$realPath = str_replace('\\', '/', $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path));`

**Magento 2.2.7**

```
/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template/File/Validator.php:113
```

code

```
protected function isPathInDirectories($path, $directories)
{
    if (!is_array($directories)) {
        $directories = (array)$directories;
    }
    foreach ($directories as $directory) {
        if (0 === strpos($this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path), $directory)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

to replace

```
protected function isPathInDirectories($path, $directories)
    {
        $realPath = str_replace('\\', '/', $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path));
        if (!is_array($directories)) {
            $directories = (array)$directories;
        }
        foreach ($directories as $directory) {
            if (0 === strpos($realPath, $directory)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks I will try it

Comment: Although this answer is right, it's not a Magento bug. The devdocs clearly say it's not supported on a Windows system. https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html

Comment: okay if this answer is right please approve it ... Thanks